# Adding optional parameters in SOAP Request in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, soap

I am using JavaScript to create a SOAP request. I have 3 input fields of which only one is mandatory. How do I make the other two optional ? I do NOT want to assign a default value to the two optional inputs

Comment: Do you want to validate the fields or what? I try to understand what this has to do with SOAP. Please post your code and explain to use where you are stuck.

Comment: This is my soap request:       
'<input name="ROLLNO" value="' + rn+ '"/>' +        
'<input name="STDX_MARKS" value="' + stdx+ '"/>' +        
'<input name="STDX11_MARKS" value="' + stdx11+ '"/>' +
'<input name="TECH_TEST" value="' + tt+ '"/>' +
<input name="COMM_TEST" value="' + ct+ '"/>' +
'<input name="SSKILLS_TEST" value="' + sst+ '"/>' +
 The input values are entered through a HTML form. Only ROLLNO is the mandatory field. So in the soap request, how can I not pass other values?